# How to detect a paragraph (<p>) in vb.net on a website

Tags: html, vb.net, email, web, browser

I'm making an application that will log you into your mojang and then read your details. 
Everything is working fine, but it gives a message on the page if you entered wrong account username/pass, and I need to read that and figure out what it is, the problem is the `<p>` doesn't have a id. Perhaps I could insert that into the webbrowser1.document?

Code Example:

Website paragraph to check:

```
<p class="error">
                    Oops, unknown username or password. If you are logging in with a Mojang account make sure to use your e-mail address as username.
        </p>
```

As you can see the class="error" and the id is non-existent.

I have what I believe is the answer, but it does not work the way I wrote it: 
`webbrowser1.document.findclass("error")`

Comment: You say the P does not have an ID but you show it with ID="test" and not a class. Can you post the html from the nearest tag WITH an ID or a class

Comment: Try `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p")
    If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "error" Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Strange, that seems like it would work but it isn't, here I've put the full actual code that I extracted btw I changed the w (in w.document...) to webBrowser1 (because thats what my element is called.

Comment: Try changing `"class"` to `"classname"`